# REST API response handling when 1 of many endpoint fails

Tags: java, rest, design-patterns, integration, api-design

I have a Java Application(REST API, Jersey) that orchestrates a lot of backend calls for the front end.
It aggregates data from all the backend systems and then returns a JSON response.

Now I have to integrate one more backend system, so I added the response from the new backend API into the Aggregate response.
This new data is not super important so I don't want to fail the entire response if this new Call fails.

What is the best elegant way to do this and also inform the clients that one of the calls failed?

Comment: The easiest solution is to let your frontend talk to each backend directly so that the frontend can decide what's important and what isn't. A less simple solution is to expect a failing call to the backend in your aggregator project and simply handle error cases properly by not including the data from that response in your aggregated response but an error message/code/status instead.

Comment: I have implemented the second solution that you suggested.
But was wondering if there is a better way to do this.